# XCode 4.4 how to permanently add files to project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, file, settings

I just started with iOS development, so pardon if this is too simple

I have a project open in XCode, and when i created a new storyboard/xib/view.h/view.m file it shows up in xcode just fine from the folder hierarchy. However, whenever i quit xcode and start xcode up again, the files disappear from the folder hierarchy. I have to manually then right click on the parent folder and do "Add files to 'project'" each and every time. (which works just fine until i restart XCode)

What's wrong with my configuration? is my xcode.proj not being modified or something? (i think it's locked under version control) If so, where can i find this file?

or is it something else that i'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project.pbxproj in your .xcodeproj directory is write protected.  Check it out with your source control system (or use a decent one like git which doesn't lock files :).

Comment: i was such a noob that i couldn't find where that file is. you simply click on the actual project ( the blue file) and there's a little lock to the top right of the file, in which you click to unlock. thanks